# Making recovery media ISO bootable on USB flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media, paragon

I am trying to "burn" the ISO recovery media file from Paragon Hard Disk Manager to a USB flash drive, but balena Etcher warns:

> The image does not appear to contain a partition table, and might not
> be recognized or bootable by your device.

[image]

Indeed, I have not been able to boot from the resulting USB flash drive.

What could be the issue and how can I get it to be bootable?

---

- Using Paragon Hard Disk Manager (version 17.10.2) Recovery Media Builder
- Paragon can output to an ISO file or removable flash media (eg. USB flash drive)
- Building directly to a USB flash drive is bootable
- The ISO file is bootable by a (VirtualBox) virtual machine when connected as a live CD/DVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to use [Ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy) to create a bootable USB flash drive which can then in turn boot the Paragon ISO file. An added benefit is that multiple ISO files can be contained simultaneously on the USB flash drive.

Another solution could be to use `isohybrid -u [ISO filename]` on linux to make the ISO 9660 file a [hybrid ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_disc). This has worked for me with other ISOs, but in this case I was getting an error "unable to find efi image". Since Ventoy got the job done I didn't investigate further.

Answer (score -2):

Balena etcher wants an iso which looks like a "linux distro" iso.

The Paragon one is built on something else (WINPE).

You could use another software to write the iso in block mode, like Rufus in DD mode (if you're on Windows) or just use dd (on Linux) to write directly on the USB drive

Comment: Hello, there are too many "might"s in your answer relatively to other content. I personally wouldn't trust it.

Comment: Indeed there were too many "might", my bad

Comment: I didn't mention it, but Paragon's recovery media can be either linux-based (Ubuntu) or WinPE-based. Both ISOs exhibit the same problem. I tried using `dd` in linux (or the Disks gnome-disk-utility), but the result is the same as with Etcher: not bootable. `Disks` shows the USB flash drive contents as "ISO 9660 (version Joliet Extension)".

Comment: If you mount the USB on Virtualbox, in passthrough, can you boot from it?

Comment: How can I boot from a USB flash drive on Virtualbox? It appears that is not natively supported and there are convoluted methods to get it to work in some cases, by using a different boot manager (Plop Boot Manager), and only with EHCI / USB2, not xHCI / USB3: https://askubuntu.com/questions/693719/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox

Comment: There are explicit direction how to do this **within Paragon**: https://kb.paragon-software.com/article/6185

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How to do what? Create recovery media directly on a removable flash media? Yes, as mention in the OP. But I prefer to save an ISO recovery file and create a bootable USB flash drive with it as needed. My question is how to achieve the latter.